# How I do to emulate a bluetooth HID keyboard in linux?

Tags: perl, bluetooth, hid, bluez

How I do in Linux, to emulate a Bluetooth HID keyboard in Linux, with perl?

I have tried with the Net::Bluetooth ( http://search.cpan.org/~addutko/Net-Bluetooth-0.41/Bluetooth.pm ) module, but can't find anywhere I put in the HID descriptor, and I can't find anywhere if I should use RFCOMM or L2CAP. (05010906a101050719e029e71500250175019508810295017508810395057501050819012905910295017503910395067508150025650507190029658100c0)

I also do NOT want to tie a physical keyboard to the Bluetooth "output" like "hidclient" do, rather I want to either expose a device similiar to "/dev/hidg0" where I can write raw HID packets (like "\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" for the key "a"), or a similiar perl interface where I can write such packets.

Also, in addition to this, I want to be able to read off some static unique serial number or similiar from the remote device (the "host" that the "emulated keyboard" is connected to) to authenticate the host to the keyboard.

I also have only found python examples of emulating HID devices. Anyone that can Point me in the right direction on how to register SDP services in Perl?